# Xiaomi does not receive a notification when the application is not running

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on an application where I am using Google Push Notification. The application receives a notification when it is running in Xiaomi phone. Otherwise, when it's killed, it does not receive a notification.

If we want to receive a notification if the application is killed then we need to allow auto restart app manually from the security app of Xiaomi. I want any trick to do this programmatically without asking the user. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

http://en.miui.com/thread-33826-1-1.html

Comment: It's working correctly in other vendor devices. "what have you tried yet?" -- I only looked on stackoverflow and attached link but didn't find any solution. If you have solution then please share otherwise writing such comment does not make sense. I don't think it's dup question

Comment: Do you have Google Framework on your phone?

Comment: @Williams I thought your question was this : "I want any trick to do this programmatically without asking user. Is there any way to do this ?" for which my statement stands valid.

Comment: @Mine It's xiaomi phone..

Comment: @Williams- I am getting exactly same issue with my xiaomi mi4. Did you able to resolve this. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Issue is, that I still receive notifications from Facebook and Whatsapp. What different they have done?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did anyone find solution?

Comment: Can anyone please tell me did you have found any solution or not ?? if yes then please comment.

Comment: Huh!! @miui sucks!!

Comment: check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/a/41360159/2798289

Answer (score 12):

From https://www.cricketbuddies.com/cricket/world-cricket-championship-2/guides/wcc2-guides, "Game Notification Fix" section:

> There are five settings that needs to be done manually in case of
> xiaomi to properly run any application. I have done a lot of research
> on this and there's no way to fix these settings programmatically.
> These are the settings:
>
> 1. Auto Start -> ON (Toggle and restart your app)
> 2. MIUI Optimization under Developer Options -> OFF
> 3. Memory Optimization under Developer Options -> LOW/OFF
> 4. No restrictions on background activities under Battery & Performance Settings
> 5. Battery Saver -> OFF
>
> There are many other devices in which the manual settings needs to be
> done in order for the app to work as expected e.g. Lenovo, some
> Micromax devices. Companies impose these kind on restrictions on
> background activities to improve the overall battery life. Some apps
> like facebook and whatsapp work correctly as these might have been
> included as system apps.

Answer (score 6):

After MIUI 6 & 7:

MIUI power saving mode is default set to "Standard" (Background access to the location services and the network will be restricted)

Where to set:

Settings -> Additional settings -> Battery & performance -> Manage apps battery usage -> Power Saving Modes -> **Set to Off** (MIUI won't restrict background activities)

Answer (score 3):

As for my understanding, once you clear apps or clear memory in the *Recent Apps* menu, [Xiaomi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaomi) (or MIUI ROM) will **force close** all the services and memory related to that app similar to user going to settings and force stopping the app.

[This link](http://en.miui.com/thread-25249-1-1.html) talks about the same issue, hence all the Broadcast receivers and Services will be ended unless started by the user again, so the notification won’t be received.

However, you can try just enabling **auto-start** for your app permissions in settings and *if* it still doesn't work, try creating a service that restarts by itself and enable **auto-start** in the settings,
AutoStart is very important in MIUI, until it’s enabled all the notification or app activity will be force closed and will never start.

Comment: How to create a service that restarts by itself?

Comment: You can do It by many ways , first try the START_STICKY ,so it tries to recreate service if its ended by system, or Just listen to onDestroy of service and try to start again

Comment: Other apps like Facebook, whatsapp etc, they send notifications even when my app is not in ROM so can you please tell me how these apps solve this issue in MI phones.

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur No, it wont run any background services if its not enabled in 'Autostart', by default all the newly installed apps are in disabled mode,  However few popular apps like FB and WhatsApp are Enabled by dafault when you install , but you can still disable them manualy and test fr urself, they wont receive any more messages

Comment: Yea i already know that, i wanted to ask what code does FB or Whatsapp have wrote so that their apps are installed by default with 'autostart' option.

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur Either that or ROM has already whitelisted some very common apps by itself without FB needing to write any code, Since MIUI does not provide any SDK of its own to control its custom settings I would go with latter

Comment: Any Update on this ?

Comment: Any one found solution?

Comment: How to find in which phone need to do auto-start code? Means I know In **MI device** it is required for auto-start But don't know about others .

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and fixed it by adding a BOOT_COMPLETED receiver to my app.

Add the following to the manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receivers.BootReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then create your BootReceiver class:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {

            Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, FBTokenService.class);
            context.startService(startServiceIntent);

            Intent notificationServiceIntent = new Intent(context, FBNotificationService.class);
            context.startService(notificationServiceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

It should work with this.

Comment: How does this work on Hybrid apps - e.g. with Cordova?\

Comment: @Rodney you could try writing a native cordova plugin?  just an idea.