# Not getting notification in Redmi phone when application is in background

Tags: android, service, notifications, broadcastreceiver

Blockquote

I am creating an application where I need to display local notification even when app is in background and if app is not in background and also when screen is off. I am getting notification in all the devices apart from Xiaomi (Redmi).

I have created a service which will run continuously and fire local notification.Removing application from stack doesnot kill serivce but I am not getting local notificatins.

I have also followed below steps but still not getting notifications :

```
1. Auto Start -> ON (Toggle and restart your app)

2.MIUI Optimization under Developer Options -> OFF

3.Memory Optimization under Developer Options -> LOW/OFF

4.No restrictions on background activities under Battery & Performance Settings
5.Battery Saver -> OFF
```

Can any one suggest ?

Comment: Please check the notification settings once

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xiaomi does not receive notification when application is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748107/xiaomi-does-not-receive-notification-when-application-is-not-running)

Comment: No , I have already tried this but it didn't solved my problem.

Comment: Can you please paste your FirebaseMessagingService code?