# MIUI 12.0.5 : Facing issues with notification sound (both custom and default ringtones)

Tags: android, audio, push-notification, issue-tracking, miui

I am facing issues in MIUI version 12.0.5(Redmi Note 7 Pro) for the app I am developing.

The application is not giving any sound for push notifications by default.
However once I enable the sound in notification settings, it works fine.

But my main problem is that I would prefer to enable the sound by default and not make my users switch it on manually, as it might not be something easy/preferable for all users.

Is there a way to enable the notification sound by deafult and not force users to do it manually?

Thanks in advance, for any responses.

Comment: I added a bounty because i am interested in knowing why some apps like Whatsapp and Telegram do not have this problem and others do. Maybe MIUI has a whitelist for big brands and f***s the small devs?

Comment: Probably helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748107/xiaomi-does-not-receive-notification-when-application-is-not-running